# calculate mean L*a*b from live preview of video in matlab gui

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In android we have simple methods to load /preview camera and calculate mean colour of a of a predefined region and display dynamically.
Is it possible to do so in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible. This post closely related to your question (on images) you can find many tools for videos

[caculate the mean of the region of interest](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/answers/17951-to-calculate-mean-of-roi-drawn-using-freehand-tool)